# Vert.X in the AppCloud

Tags: swisscomdev

Is it planned to support Vert.X in Swisscom's Application Cloud? I'm thinking about a `service` which could be added to `apps`. I guess ultimately it would only need a Hazelcast service to support Vert.X, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can already run non-clustered Vert.x apps on Swisscom Application cloud and there are commercial/productive apps doing so.

As you've mentioned, you would need Hazelcast for Vert.X to run in clustered mode. Hazelcast relies on TCP for communication between cluster members and this is currently not supported on Swisscom Application Cloud however this might change soon.

Moreover, there are currently no plans to offer Hazelcast as a service in the near future.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I don't seem to see the benefit of Vert.X if you run it in a non-clustered mode. I guess I will have to write my own implementation as soon as you allow TCP for communication to figure out the instance's IP address to set-up a cluster.